# Import not working with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm importing object to a `.ts` file but it is `undefined`, when I do the same with `require` keyword , then it is working. But I'd like to understand whats happening

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'); // working
import {jwt2} from 'jsonwebtoken'; // not working
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first example is importing the entire module, while the second one is trying to import a member of the module named `jwt2`, but [there is no such member](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/index.js).  To import the entire module using `import`, try:

```
import * as jwt2 from 'jsonwebtoken';
```